# Why is Unity locking animatable attributes?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

Example:

> When I add "shrink" (changing scale) animation to my Image and hit
>   play, I can't change the scale of this Image at runtime even using
>   editor scaling tool.

Is it possible to prevent that and be able to edit this parameter at runtime without triggering the animation?

Comment: You can change the `Scale` of a `GameObject` (In your case the Image), by going to the `Inspector` tab and changing the `scale` property of the `transform` section.

Answer (score 1):

Because the animation is updating and setting the value every frame, overriding your changes.

Comment: Is there workaround for that? For example I want to freely scale object once animation ended (and will never run again)

Comment: GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;